# What host does Kubernetes assign to my deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, microservices

I have two Kubernetes deployments: `composite-app` (1 pod) and `product-app` (2 pods), both listening in port 8080. The first one needs to call the second one sometimes.

However, the first deployment can't find the second one. When it tries to call it using the `product.app` host it fails:

> Exception: I/O error on GET request for "http://product-app:8080/product/123": product-app;
> nested exception is UnknownHostException

Am I using the right host? So far I've tried (to no avail):

- `product`
- `product-app.default.pod.cluster.local`
- `product-app`

Here's my YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: composite-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: composite-app
  ports:
    - targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080
      nodePort: 30091
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: composite-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: composite-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: composite-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: composite-container
        image: 192.168.49.2:2376/composite-ms:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: product-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: product-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: product-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: product-container
        image: 192.168.49.2:2376/product-ms:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

Comment: In the manifest I did not see a service for product-app. If the composite app pods need to access the product app containers, then you first need to create a service for product-app (with a selector 'app: product-app' and port 8080). After this is done ```http://product-app``` will resolve to the product app pods within the cluster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a `Service` object for the `product-deploy` `Deployment` as well for the other pod to be able to connect to it. The `Service` can be of type `ClusterIP` if it is not needed to be exposed to the external world.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: product-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    app: product-app
  ports:
    - targetPort: 8080
      port: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: product-deploy
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: product-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: product-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: product-container
        image: 192.168.49.2:2376/product-ms:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

You can connect to the other pod using the pod's IP without the service. However, that is not recommended since the pod's IP can be changed across pod updates.

You can then connect to the `product-app` pod from the `composite-app` using `product-service`.

Comment: actually, it is already mentioned correctly: `You can then connect to the product-app pod from the composite-app using product-service`, please let me know if you see anything wrong here and I can fix it?

Comment: My bad. I misread the answer. Still learning the ropes of this. Thanks again.